# Assigning method from h file

Tags: objective-c

Hi I am new to the object-c and this might be silly question. I studied that I have to assign the name of the method on the header file(.h file) before I make a logic in m file. But I found some of examples assigning method only in the m file not from h file. And it works ok. I'm slightly confused what to follow now. Please explain me the difference.

Answer (score 1):

All methods that shall be publicly available in your project go to the .h-file. If you want the method to be kind of private, don't add it to the h.-file but define it in the .m-file.

Answer (score 0):

The newest versions of Xcode include a compiler that allows you to skip the declaration in the header file if you just are going to use the method in the same .m file in which it is defined.

That is probably what you have seen.

The same newer versions of Xcode also allow you to declare ivars in the .m file, which also contributes to simpler header files and a higher degree of locality in the implementation files.

Comment: This isn't a new feature of the compiler. It has never been necessary to declare methods in the header. Doing so is only necessary if the method is to be known in translation units (.m files, basically) other than the one which implements the class.

Comment: @KenThomases you're right of course, but I am pretty sure that in the earlier versions (gcc) you would have to define the method before you referenced it, while now you can reference a method that is defined further down in the file.

Comment: You would have to either declare or define a method before you call it, yes, and the latest versions of clang no longer require that.